# Can't download Teradata Vantage Express 16.20

Tags: teradata, vmware, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I can't do a simple download of any Teradata software such as Vantage Express 16.20.  I keep getting this message.

[access denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oMKN.png)

Comment: Add your code here. don't send the picture of the code.

Comment: Looks like you may be following a direct link to a file without getting credentials from the portal. Are you logged in to the downloads.teradata.com site? Did you get prompted and accept the EULA? If you still have an issue, contact the admin for that site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I tried again in a different browser, Chrome kept giving me an "access denied" error, however Safari allowed me to download from Teradata's website without issue.

Likely a problem / misconfiguration on Teradata's side.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a chrome browser-related safety feature because of the file extension and terraform's redirect URL.
Even though Firefox has considered it malicious it gave me an option to download and I could download it.